# Chromedriver redirects to chrome-error://chromewebdata/ and displays a blank screen, even though the request goes through to the end of the script

Tags: php, docker, selenium-chromedriver, codeception, circleci

***Context***: I'm setting up a browser testing build in my CircleCI pipeline.

***Description***: When I send a request to my local vhost with chromedriver using codeception, I get a **blank screen** and the  **url is chrome-error://chromewebdata/**. When I curl the url, it works as expected.

I'm **confident that apache is finding the app** and the **script is executing correctly** since a log I placed at the end of the script is coming through. But then for some reason I get redirected to that weird chrome page (of which I can't seem to find much info on except that it means my app can't be accessed) and a blank screen. Nothing valuable in the chrome, PHP, or apache logs. I can also confirm that chromedriver seems to be working fine as I'm able to access other sites - like google, etc - with no issues.

And the test suite works fine locally, but not in the CircleCi build server

***Summary***: So, **basically**, chromedriver works with other sites (e.g. google.com), but doesn't work with my app, where curl has no problem. But I am confident the script of my app is being executed due to the log. And this behaviour only occours on the CircleCi temp/build server.

**Other details**

- Running the inside a docker image
- ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.79
- Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
- PHP 7.2
- Codeception 3.1

*Thanks for any help*